# Loop through JSON Object Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift5

I am trying to iterate through a JSON object and obtain specific values in the swift programming language.

I am receiving a JSON like so

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
let charges = json["charges"] as? [String:Any]
```

**json:**

```
{
  object: 'list',
  data: [
    {
      id: 'ch_1IWQEfKn7R1M6tqnhrpyIhMk',
      object: 'charge',
      amount: 555,
      amount_captured: 555,
      amount_refunded: 0,
      application: 'ca_IXRQuoBh5mSJXXpEccXssma6Oz0u3HjX',
      application_fee: 'fee_1IWQEfKn7R1M6tqnvTHQeSEF',
      application_fee_amount: 6,
      balance_transaction: 'txn_1IWQEfKn7R1M6tqnkK9LCNuM',
      billing_details: [Object],
      calculated_statement_descriptor: 'TEST ACCOUNT',
      captured: true,
      created: 1616090777,
      currency: 'usd',
      customer: null,
      description: null,
      destination: null,
      dispute: null,
      disputed: false,
      failure_code: null,
      failure_message: null,
      fraud_details: {},
      invoice: null,
      livemode: false,
      metadata: {},
      on_behalf_of: null,
      order: null,
      outcome: [Object],
      paid: true,
      payment_intent: 'pi_1IWQEeKn7R1M6tqnYbGfFCzg',
      payment_method: 'pm_1IWQEeKn7R1M6tqnKLxSg6vZ',
      payment_method_details: [Object],
      receipt_email: null,
      receipt_number: null,
      receipt_url: 'https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1ISouBKn7R1M6tqn/ch_1IWQEfKn7R1M6tqnhrpyIhMk/rcpt_J8hdy05N6VfOmRECdumpti8Jiljz2Et',
      refunded: false,
      refunds: [Object],
      review: null,
      shipping: null,
      source: null,
      source_transfer: null,
      statement_descriptor: null,
      statement_descriptor_suffix: null,
      status: 'succeeded',
      transfer_data: null,
      transfer_group: null
    },
    {
      id: 'ch_1IU62QKn7R1M6tqnbXXlOpch',
      object: 'charge',
      amount: 5599,
      amount_captured: 5599,
      amount_refunded: 0,
      application: 'ca_IXRQuoBh5mSJXXpEccXssma6Oz0u3HjX',
      application_fee: 'fee_1IU62RKn7R1M6tqnLle3zblA',
      application_fee_amount: 56,
      balance_transaction: 'txn_1IU62RKn7R1M6tqn3ttu9F3N',
      billing_details: [Object],
      calculated_statement_descriptor: 'TEST ACCOUNT',
      captured: true,
      created: 1615536482,
      currency: 'usd',
      customer: null,
      description: null,
      destination: null,
      dispute: null,
      disputed: false,
      failure_code: null,
      failure_message: null,
      fraud_details: {},
      invoice: null,
      livemode: false,
      metadata: {},
      on_behalf_of: null,
      order: null,
      outcome: [Object],
      paid: true,
      payment_intent: 'pi_1IU62NKn7R1M6tqnWSOLJVge',
      payment_method: 'pm_1IU62PKn7R1M6tqnIyOUgUMX',
      payment_method_details: [Object],
      receipt_email: null,
      receipt_number: null,
      receipt_url: 'https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1ISouBKn7R1M6tqn/ch_1IU62QKn7R1M6tqnbXXlOpch/rcpt_J6Id30gjIhQU6AWPBHgUXoujbhFOTyf',
      refunded: false,
      refunds: [Object],
      review: null,
      shipping: null,
      source: null,
      source_transfer: null,
      statement_descriptor: null,
      statement_descriptor_suffix: null,
      status: 'succeeded',
      transfer_data: null,
      transfer_group: null
    },
    {
      id: 'ch_1IU60cKn7R1M6tqny9o2NV5W',
      object: 'charge',
      amount: 1000,
      amount_captured: 1000,
      amount_refunded: 0,
      application: 'ca_IXRQuoBh5mSJXXpEccXssma6Oz0u3HjX',
      application_fee: 'fee_1IU60cKn7R1M6tqn95nUHETe',
      application_fee_amount: 10,
      balance_transaction: 'txn_1IU60cKn7R1M6tqnZKNbSEXf',
      billing_details: [Object],
      calculated_statement_descriptor: 'TEST ACCOUNT',
      captured: true,
      created: 1615536370,
      currency: 'usd',
      customer: null,
      description: null,
      destination: null,
      dispute: null,
      disputed: false,
      failure_code: null,
      failure_message: null,
      fraud_details: {},
      invoice: null,
      livemode: false,
      metadata: {},
      on_behalf_of: null,
      order: null,
      outcome: [Object],
      paid: true,
      payment_intent: 'pi_1IU60ZKn7R1M6tqnrUSK1TQD',
      payment_method: 'pm_1IU60bKn7R1M6tqnAUHQXqJG',
      payment_method_details: [Object],
      receipt_email: null,
      receipt_number: null,
      receipt_url: 'https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1ISouBKn7R1M6tqn/ch_1IU60cKn7R1M6tqny9o2NV5W/rcpt_J6Ib5PEZQzEgyXWoOwKcxZ9x7mByCVu',
      refunded: false,
      refunds: [Object],
      review: null,
      shipping: null,
      source: null,
      source_transfer: null,
      statement_descriptor: null,
      statement_descriptor_suffix: null,
      status: 'succeeded',
      transfer_data: null,
      transfer_group: null
    }
  ],
  has_more: true,
  url: '/v1/charges'
}
```

How can I iterate through the JSON object to receive "amount", "currency", and "id".

For example PSUEDO:

```
for item in charges {
    print(item["amount"])
    print(item["currency"])
    print(item["id"])
}
```

I may be initializing the json improperly such as

> json["charges"] as? [String:Any]

Comment: JSON seems like not correct. Post correct JSON.

Comment: @Harish i have update the json object

Comment: Point one, don't use `try ?`. Use `do/try/catch` so that you can report errors rather than simply throwing them away.  Point 2, create appropriate structs for your data and use `Codable` and `JSONDecoder` rather `JSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `try ?` - This throws away errors.  Always use `do/try/catch` so that you handle any errors that occur, even if you just print them.

`JSONSerialization` and decoding JSON to arrays and dictionaries isn't best practice.  It is much better to create suitable structs that conform to `Codable` and use `JSONDecoder`.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var object: String
    var hasMore: Bool
    var data: [ResponseData]
    var url: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case object
        case hasMore = "has_more"
        case url
        case data
    }
}

struct ResponseData: Codable {
    var amount: Int
    var currency: String
    var id: String
}
```

For simplicity I have't added all of the properties to the `ResponseData` struct, just the ones you have said you are interested in

```
do {
   let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
   json.data.forEach { charge in
      print(charge.id)
      print(charge.currency)
      print(charge.ammount)
   }
} catch {
   print("Error! \(error)")
}
```